# Active Directory: Allow users of different domain to login

Tags: authentication, active-directory, trust

We currently have all of our servers in domain A.

But many users from a different department also need to log in on our systems, however, their devices are registered in domain B.

What kind of trust should I set up to allow the users of domain B to log in on our server in domain A.

I assume a one way trust is sufficient to be able to add domain B users to our domain A user groups in the Active Directory? But what direction should it be?

Does that mean that I will be adding the users like domainB\user1 to domainA\group1. Or do I have to redefine domainB\user1 in domain A as domainA\user1 (with the same username and password) and then add domainA\user1 to domainA\group1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a one-way trust will likely do. A one-way trust essentially means "Domain A trusts that Domain B users are who they say they are".

So if Domain A trusts Domain B, then you will be able to add Domain B users to Domain A groups.

The opposite will not be true, unless you make a two-way trust.

Comment: Will I be able to add the users from domain B to domain A groups from the "Active Directory Users and Computers" tool of domain A or do I need to log in on the domain B domain controller to do that?
Will I be directly adding the users from domain B to my groups or do I have to recreate the users with the same username in my own domain? (Check my question, I have added some more information)

Comment: You will add the users directly (you do not have to create duplicate accounts on Domain A). However, the groups will have to have a group scope of Domain Local. They cannot be Global or Universal.

Comment: So domain A will have an outgoing trust and domain B will have an incoming trust right?